# Add two or more time data values in mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net, time, mysql-workbench

I'm currently working on a project using vb.net and mysql database I just wanna ask how would I be able to sum up 2 or more entries of time in a column in mysql workbench formatted as hh:mm:sec.

For example I have this data stored on my database:

```
|03:45:00|
|03:12:00|
|03:08:57|
```

**Sample Table**

[image]

The total should be **10:05:02**

I've tried to sum the entire column data using this query but I think I'm doing it wrong.

```
Select sum(Hours_worked) as Total 
    from db_project 
where 
   Date_of_entry between '2019-02-04' and '2019-02-15' 
order by 
   Date_of_entry asc;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly add time values to each other using [`SUM`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum). Instead, you need to convert them to a value which can be summed (numeric) for example using [`TIME_TO_SEC`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec). You can then convert the sum back to a time format (using [`SEC_TO_TIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time) and [`TIME_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format)) for display:

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(Hours_worked))), '%H:%i:%s') AS Total
FROM db_project
WHERE Date_of_entry BETWEEN '2019-02-04' AND '2019-02-15'
```

Output:

```
10:06:02
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ae528edc8dd025f8394c3be9ffb4a7d5)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just added some modification on the query then it works perfectly on my project.